# is there another command should i use?

Tags: discord.py

So, I can't use the "?roast" command and "?roast @(user)" at the same time...

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd, activity=discord.Game(' "?" Booe'))
    print('Bot is ready to play!')
```

```
@client.command()
async def roast(ctx, member:discord.Member):
   
    roast_messages = [
     f'{ctx.message.author.mention}You are useless as the UEUE in Queue {member.mention}',

    ]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(roast_messages))
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your question a bit more, it wasn't very clear and pretty choppy.
Well, the `roast` is already defined as another command so try making another command named differently than `roast`? lmk if that works and show me how you did that

Comment: okay, my bad, so with this command, when i write "?roast + users" works fine but when i try "?roast" i got this error
`discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.`

Comment: yeah! The reason it says it's missing an argument is that in your async def like you have `member :discord.Member` is being called, so when you just do ?roast without a member it won't work cause no member was implied. Also, you can just do `ctx.author.mention` instead of ctx.message.author.mention` they both work but its just unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a way to solve that , discord gives us a way like this

```py
@client.command()
async def roast(ctx, member:discord.Member=None):#None is if nothing is given then its None
    if member == None:
       member = ctx.author
    roast_messages = [
     f'{ctx.message.author.mention}You are useless as the UEUE in Queue {member.mention}',]
    await ctx.send("imagine roasting yourself")#Your Choice Absolutely :)
    await ctx.send(random.choice(roast_messages))
```

here if the member isnt specified , the function is called taking member as none , later gives the none value to the ctx.author itself (dont try to write ctx.author instead of none in the `async def roast` it gives error as ctx aint defined. also i forgot your roast messages wont make sense then so make sure to edit them too TY :)